# What hook to use changing image field description

Tags: theming

I wonder how I can alter the description of the custom image field. I can't use hook_form_alter. I couldn't find the variable. Please advise. Thanks!

[image]e.g

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alternate text field is added by [image_field_widget_process()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/image_field_widget_process/7), which is the process element function added by [image_field_widget_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/image_field_widget_form/7) (an implementation of [hook_field_widget_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form/7)). To alter it, you can add your element process function with [hook_field_widget_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form_alter/7).

```
function mymodule_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  if ($context['field']['type'] == 'image' && $context['instance']['widget']['type'] == 'image_image' && !empty($context['instance']['settings']['alt_field'])) {
    foreach (element_children($element) as $delta) {
      $element[$delta]['#process'][] = 'mymodule_field_widget_process';
    }
  }
}

function mymodule_field_widget_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  // Verify the element is accessible to the currently logged-in user.
  // Differently, it will not be visible to the user, and it is useless to alter the description, or the title.
  if ($element['alt']['#access']) {
    // Use $element['alt']['#title'] for the title.
    // Use $element['alt']['#description'] for the description.
  }

  return $element;
}
```

The reason I would use `hook_field_widget_form_alter()` instead of `hook_form_alter()` is that the first has direct access to some information the latter doesn't get, such as the settings for the field instance, and the field settings. In this case, I can access `$context['instance']['settings']['alt_field']` to check if the field requires the alternate text field.

If you are going to use `hook_form_alter()`, remember that:

- A field could have more than one widget, if the user is allowed to enter multiple values.
- When its #access property is set to `FALSE`, a form element is not accessible to the currently logged-in user; in that case, it is useless to change any other properties for the form element, as it will not be shown to the user.

Comment: Thanks, yes hook_field_widget_form_alter is the best form_alter hook to use to add the process callback there. Answer updated for clarification.

Comment: Actually, you didn't update your answer: You changed it to suggest the same hook I am suggesting.

Comment: I initially wrote "form_alter", then changed to hook_form_alter. The actual form_alter hook could be field_widget_form_alter (best) hook_form_alter hook_FORM_ID_alter etc.. apologies for any offense there. I've changed it back to the origin "form_alter"

Comment: No offense taken. Just to better state what I was saying, `hook_form_alter()`, and `hook_field_widget_form_alter()` are two different hooks which take different arguments; the latter is not the `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` variant either.

Comment: Thanks @Kiamlaluno, I have tested the code, 2 places need to amend in order to make this work actually. 1) $context['field']['type'] == 'image_image', should be 'image'.  2) 'element_children($elements)' and '$elements[$delta]..' should be 'element_children($element)' and  '$element[$delta]..', the '$elements' should be  singular.  Correct me if I am wrong. Besides, i wonder how to narrow down this code to apply only to a specific content type .e.g 'slideshow', instead of all content types.

Comment: @Adamtan I have updated the code to use `$context['instance']['widget']['type']`, as a field can use more than one widget, and you want to alter a single widget type (image_image). Using `$elements` instead of `$element` was a typo. `:)`

Comment: Great thanks! @kiamlaluno. You are right, a field can use more than one widget. I have tested and your updated code works perfectly now. Besides, I use `$context['form']['type']['#value'] == 'gallery'` to narrow down only to my gallery content type without affecting others. Thanks for your help and guidance really. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

That text is added by

[image_field_widget_process](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/image_field_widget_process/7)

You can alter it using form_alter to add your own process callback to the element.

See also

[image_field_widget_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/image_field_widget_form/7) for some additional info, e.g the process callback added by `$elements[$delta]['#process'][] = 'image_field_widget_process';`

Alternatively, a module solution is to use

[stringoverrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides)

and translate the text via the admin user interface.

Comment: The String Overrides module changes every instance of the string. It cannot be used to change a string only in specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

Although @kiamlaluno's answer comes close, it's returning a blank image field for me. Here's a modified solution that worked.

```
// Alter image field Alt Title & Description
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  // Replace field_MYFIELD with your field name
  if ($context['field']['field_name'] == 'field_MYFIELD') {
    // Loop through the element children
    foreach (element_children($element) as $key => $child) {
      // Add the new process function to the element
      $element[$key]['#process'][] = 'MYMODULE_image_field_widget_process';
    }
  }
}

function MYMODULE_image_field_widget_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  // Change the title field label and description
  $element['alt']['#title'] = 'Effect';
  $element['alt']['#description'] = '{effect options}';

  // Return the altered element
  return $element;
}
```

Answer is inspired by a [duplicate question asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409085).